# Search MongoDB document subarray using Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have the following MongoDB document structure that I am trying to query;

```
{
  "key": [{
      "1": [
        2,
        3,
        4
      ]
    },
    {
      "2": [
        1
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want is all documents having inside the `key` field having their sub field as "1". The array associated with that is [2,3,4] which are java Long values. I am trying to do the above logic with the following code with no luck;

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("key.1", null);
MongoCursor<BasicDBObject> cursor = collection.find(query).iterator();
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(cursor.next());
}
```

The reason I am associating `key.1` with null in the query object is because I don't care what the values in the array is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing couple of things here.

`key.1` is conflicting dot notation syntax for querying the sub fields with numeric string name.

This will conflict with indexed based access for the array `key`.

`BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("key.1", null);` in effect is asking Mongo to query for a `key` array for a value / document at index 1 for a `null` value . This would have matched if you had something like

```
{
  "key": 
    [
      {"1":"one"},
      null
    ] 
}
```

Okay now coming back to post. You've to use `$exist` operator if you don't care about value. The shell filter will be `{"key":{"$elemMatch":{"1":{ $exists: true}}}}`. Note the use of `$elemMatch` to do field level comparison as dot notation is conflicting with index style access. For string name fields the dot notation & elemMatch works similarly for embedded arrays for queries involving single query condition.

Java code

```
BasicDBObject exists = new BasicDBObject("$exists", true);
BasicDBObject field = new BasicDBObject("1", exists);
BasicDBObject elemMatch = new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch", field);
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("key", elemMatch);
```

More info about operators and syntax.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much for the links.